# な, の, である and ために

Tags: grammar

When used with a noun ために could have two meanings :

> (1) 学生のために、奨学金がある。
>
> There are scholarships *for (the sake of)* students.
>
> (2) 学生のために、学校の規則に従わなければならない。
>
> Since s/he is a student s/he has to obey the rules set by her/his school.

With the second meaning, it is possible to express "the state of being a student". Indeed, I can rephrase the second translation as "Since s/he is in the state of being a student s/he" has to obey the rules set by her/his school.
Thus it is possible to express this state in the past.

> (3) 学生だったために、学校の規則に従わなければならなかった.
>
> Since s/he was (in the state of being) a student, she had to obey the rules set by her/his school.

In this sense of expressing a state, の is equivalent to である, right ?

So I can rephrase (2) as 学生であるために、... and since である and だ are somewhat equivalent I should be able to rewrite this as 学生なために (since な is the 連体形 of だ).

So the question is: Is all this possible or mere speculation ?

Comment: We say 規則に従う, not 規則を従う.

Comment: Good question but I think (?!) that your "rephrased" sentence 2 is degraded if である is replaced with な. This contrasts with having の　（original sentence 2
), which is a perfect sentence because it can be analyzed as NP+the zero form copula+の.　This would not be the case if the NP was 形容動詞.（NP=noun phrase)

Comment: @Tim, Yes, I also have the feeling that the use of な is not correct but I can't figure out the why. This is in fact the core of the question. On the other hand your analysis : NP+the zero form copula+の explains why である is not used in general.

Comment: I would say #2 can *only* be `学生であるために`.  Saying it as `学生のために` sound wrong to my ear, but this is just my intuition.

Comment: @istrasci, that's funny because my reference book (A dictionnary of basic japanese p. 446 here) does not mention the alternative with である at all.

Comment: @Lyle:  Hmm, I have that dictionary too.  I'll have to check it out when I get home.

Comment: If you go by the standard textbooks or Makino then な sounds wrong and ~であるため is grammatically the same as ~行くため. If you look at it as a linguist and cases where な can replace である and the different uses of の then it may not be so clear cut but I don't have a reference to cite and have not really tried to work it (yet).

Comment: @Tim, Indeed, according to ADoBJG, the use of な is wrong for nouns and your explanation (N+zero form copula+の) explains why noun does not require な to modify (修飾) because they are plain nouns and の act somewhat like a "genitive" case particle. But the trick that である then だ in the form of な leads me to wonder. It seems to be a case of the である・だ-duality where だ and である are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all the reasoning above is just mere speculation. Now is the why (I'm not sure to use the good terms so feel free to edit if you think it is necessary).

The major difference between だ and である is that である is a real verb (ie. it is not defective) but だ is not. So there is no restriction in the use of the 連体形 of である but according to [助動詞_(国文法) (wikipedia)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E_%28%E5%9B%BD%E6%96%87%E6%B3%95%29) 5th note below the fisrt chart there is this sentence the な-連体形 of だ is limited to a few cases:

> 助詞「の」「ので」「のに」等が続く場合に使われる。連体形だが名詞を修飾することはできない。なお、形容動詞を品詞と認めない立場では別の考え方になる。

Which translate to ([thanks to Choko](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17934/4216)):

> Those 連体形 (=「そうな」「べきな」「な」 and 「です」) can be followed by particles 「の」「ので」「のに」etc...
>
> > 例: そうなの・べきなの・なの・ですの
> >        そうなので・べきなので・なので・ですので
> >        そうなのに・べきなのに・なのに・ですのに
>
> ... but cannot modify nouns (=cannot be followed by nouns).
>
> > 例: *そうな机・*べきな机・*な机・*です机
>
> By the way, those who don't recognize na-adjectives as a part of speech (=those who deny na-adjectives) think differently (eg. they consider きれいな机 as "きれい + 助動詞「だ(な)」+ noun", not as "na-adjective + noun").

This explains why な could not be used in this case.